# How to simple and safe call a nullable delegate with await

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, nullreferenceexception, func

I have `func<Task>` delegates in my project which can be null. Is there any way to make the call of such a delegate simpler as displayed below?

```cs
public async Task Test()
{
    Func<Task> funcWithTask = null;

    await (funcWithTask != null ? funcWithTask.Invoke() : Task.CompletedTask);
}
```

Comment: You can use null propagation: await funcWithTask?.Invoke()??Task.CompletedTask; The same you're doing but more compact.

Comment: Or initialize the Func<Task> with a default of `Func<Task> funcWithTask = () => Task.CompletedTask;`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft That is a good idea, but to be safe I have to prevented possible null assignments later on.

Comment: In C# 8+ the compiler can help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any way to make the call of such a delegate simpler as displayed below?

There are alternatives:

```
if (funcWithTask != null) await funcWithTask();
```

Or:

```
await (funcWithTask?.Invoke() ?? Task.CompletedTask);
```

The second uses the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?.`, which only calls `Invoke()` when `funcWithTask` is not null, and the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) `??` which returns the right-hand operand when the left hand operand is null (`Task.CompletedTask` in this case).

Comment: if `funcWithTask` has return value, likes a string, you can try this alternatice:
`var taskResult = await (funcWithTask?.Invoke() ?? Task.FromResult(string.Empty));`